# GPG error with Mint Repository on Debian

Tags: debian, linux-mint

When I update the packages of a Debian installation, I receive the following error:

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.linuxmint.com debian Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3EE67F3D0FF405B2
```

I have added the Mint repository to a Debian installation, to have access to specific packages.

How can I fix that error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find and add that key.

Often something like this will work

```
gpg --keyserver wwwkeys.uk.pgp.net --recv-keys 3EE67F3D0FF405B2
gpg --armor --export 3EE67F3D0FF405B2 | sudo apt-key add -
```

But mixing repositories for different debian distributions are rarely a good idea. As a bare minimum you should set up apt pinning to give that repo a low priority, else you run the risk of random packages being "upgraded" to the version from that repo, and that might break stuff.